# ReactJS Sort Method doesn't work with multiple condition

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have an app that I wrote with React native, and there is an array that I want to sort by different properties. But no matter what I do, I can't see a change reflected on the screen. It seems sort method doesn't work at all. Please help me, I leave the code below.

```
    const sortDirection=useRef('');
    
     let filteredList = useMemo(() => {
          return list?.filter((data) => {
            return (
              isDataSelected(data, gender, "gender") &&
              isDataSelected(data, filterCategory, "branchname")&&
              isDataSelected(data,location?.toUpperCase(),"cityname") &&
              isDataSelected(data,name,"name")&&
            );
          });
      }, [gender,filterCategory,location,name]);
    
    const sortBy=(sortDirection)=>{
        if(sortDirection==='alphabetic'){
          return filteredList?.sort((a,b)=>b.name.localeCompare(a.name));
        }else if(sortDirection==='reverseAlphabetic'){
          return filteredList?.sort((a,b)=>a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
        }else if(sortDirection==='purse'){
          return filteredList?.sort((a,b)=>a.price.localeCompare(b.price));
        }else if(sortDirection==='reversePurse'){
          return filteredList?.sort((a,b)=>b.price.localeCompare(a.price));
        }else if(sortDirection==='reverseRating'){
          return filteredList?.sort(function(a,b){return b.score.localeCompare(a.score)});
        }else if(sortDirection==='rating'){
          return filteredList?.sort((a,b)=>a.score.localeCompare(b.score));
        }else if(sortDirection==='branchAlphabetic'){
          return filteredList?.sort((a,b)=>b.branchname.localeCompare(a.branchname));
        }else{
          return filteredList?.sort((a,b)=>a.branchname.localeCompare(b.branchname));
        }
      };

<FlatList data={filteredList?filteredList:list} .../>
```

Comment: try to add extraData property to <FlatList /> with your sort direction value. For example <FlatList extraData={sortDirection.current} ... /> . And what is filteredList?filteredList:list ??

Comment: filteredList depends on the list state which I am pulling data from the api, so I added a condition to the flatlist data

Comment: Have you logged each sorted data on console, is every sort return right data.

Comment: Yes I tried, but there is no change in filtered list